# are the members of a static inner class by default static in java

Tags: java

```
public static class ViewHolder {

        public int a,b;
            public void method();


    }
```

are the method and the variables a and b by default static when I declare the class as static or do I have to separately declare them static ? I know its a noobish question but I am a little confused right now :(

Comment: Do you know what it means for an inner class to be static?

Comment: I know as i am using it ...I am working on a viewholder pattern in android which requires one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, when you declare an inner static class you specify that the *declaration itself is static*, so that you don't need an object instance of the parent class to access it.

Nothing regarding inner members is involed.

Answer (score 6):

No, they're not static by default, they're normal instance members.

Static inner classes, unlike normal inner classes, *can* have static members, though, if you explicitly declare them.

Answer (score 1):

The members of the Static nested class are not static. `static` keyword is specified with the class which signifies that the nested class can be instantiated with the containing outer class similar to static data member.

```
BaseClass.StaticNestedClass nestedClass = new BaseClass.StaticNestedClass();
nestedClass.nonStaticMethod();//correct
BaseClass.StaticNestedClass.nonStaticMethod()//Error
```

This has no effect on the data members of the static nested class which behave as normal class.

Please note if a `static` keyword is associated with a `class` then the class **has to be a nested class**

Answer (score 0):

A public static class works just like any other class.  The only real difference is that it is accessed through the containing class:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass foo = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
```